# função executando ação mesmo sendo false

Tags: javascript

bom eu estou fazendo um trabalho da faculdade, e tem uma tela de listagem de arquivos, na hora de excluir eu criei um botão com onclick, não entendo muito de javascript, porem seguindo a lógica do if else ele deveria executar apenas a ação se fosse verdadeiro, mais mesmo se eu cancelar ele executa;

```js
<script>
function apagar(){
var res = confirm("Deseja Apagar a questão ?");
    if (res == false){
        var href = this.href;
    }else{
        alert("Cancelado");
    }
}
</script>
```

```html
<a href="apagar_questao.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="btn_apagar" onclick="apagar()">Apagar</button></a>
```

Comment: Na sua condição do if não deveria ser `if(res == true)` não?

Comment: qualquer um dos dois que eu coloco ele executa a ação, sendo true ou false ele executa o href

Comment: O problema é que vc não deve colocar um botão dentro de um link. Link é link, botão é botão, não se deve misturar as duas coisas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que você esta colocando a função em um elemento que está dentro de um href, ou seja, independente do valor que for `true` ou `false` ele vai seguir para a próxima página.
O que pode ser feito e redirecionar com `window.location`. Se houver mesmo a necessidade da tag `a` você pode colocar `javascript:void(0)` que ele não direciona pada lugar nenhum.

O código seria assim.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function apagar(idRes){
var res = confirm("Deseja Apagar a questão ?");
    if (res){
      window.location = "apagar_questao.php?id="+idRes;
      }else{
       alert("Cancelado");
     }
   }
</script>
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="btn_apagar" onclick="apagar(<?php echo $linhas['id'];?>)">Apagar</button></a>
```

Comment: <a href="apagar_questao.php?&id=<?php echo $linhas['id']; ?>">  e quando eu tenho que pegar o id ? para enviar como eu deveria fazer

Comment: Eu modifiquei a resposta para você ver como irá ficar, nesse caso você pode passar o `id` em php via parâmetro da função no botão. Depois no Javascript você concatena o id com o link.

Comment: vou tentar aqui, mt obrigado

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente, agradeço mesmo :D, lhe desejo muito sucesso, eu jamais conseguiria fazer esse código com o pouco de conhecimento que tenho. Um grande abraço.

Comment: No começo é sempre assim. :D mas por que não faz isso com `submit` de um formulário? e quando você verificar tudo você permite que ele siga dê o `submit`.